# cómo hacer que el navegador no corte tablas al imprimir

Tags: html, div, imprimir, tablas

Necesito hacer que el navegador no corte las tablas al llegar a la otra página.  Intente con varios métodos que encontre en la web, pero no logro hacer que funcione.  El problema se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente lo siguiente:

```
@media all {
   div.saltopagina{
      display: none;
   }
}

@media print{
   div.saltopagina{ 
      display:block; 
      page-break-before:always;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede prevenir de la siguiente manera

```
<table class="print-friendly">
    <!-- Aquí iría el resto de la tabla -->
</table>

<style> 
    table.print-friendly tr td, table.print-friendly tr th {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
</style>
```

**DISCLAIMER**
Este comportamiento del CSS funciona en tanto la impresión se haga directamente desde el navegador y no utilizando alguna librería que genere archivos PDF, si esto se esta haciendo desde una librería que este generando PDF podría no comportarse igual y sería necesario revisar la documentación sobre como prevenirlo.

Comment: La corta igual, la tabla está dentro de un div con position relative

Comment: Para el div puede agregar la siguiente directiva CSS `@media print { div{ page-break-inside: avoid; } }`

Comment: tampoco funciona